# How to not show a component to a dynamic end url in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, components, router

Hey there I have no idea how to hide a component such as Header to a component which has a dynamic url. For example:

```
path="/reviews/:reviewId"
```

the `reviewId` is dynamic so it changes and for a known url I know how to hide a component, but I have no idea how to hide it for a dynamic path. I mean I could use an array with all `id` in database but if there are thousands it is not something I would like to have as it slows the process. Anyone has a solution??

Comment: Is there some logic to which of the `reviewId`s won't see the component?

Comment: in this case i do not want to show the header to this route at all

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a `function` like

```
//...
headerClass: function(path) {
    //Implement me
}
//...
```

you could set the `className` property like

```
className={this.headerClass(path)}
```

Comment: I defined a list of routes i want to show a component and then i applied for the one not mentioned this logic:   if (inclusionArray.indexOf( props.location.pathname) < 0) {
      return null
  }